# Simulate db operation in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to simulate an *async* db operation in AngularJs. ( via `setTimeout`).

I have this factory function  code :([**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/EZIPEdiC/2/edit)) 
which uses an internal `array`  :

```
 shoppingModule.factory('Items', function() {
        var items = {};
        items.query = function() {
          // In real apps, we'd pull this data from the server...
          return [
            {title: 'Paint pots', description: 'Pots full of paint', price: 3.95},
            {title: 'Polka dots', description: 'Dots with polka', price: 2.95},
            {title: 'Pebbles', description: 'Just little rocks', price: 6.95}
          ];
        };
        return items;
      });
```

The `controller` , in turn  calls :

```
 function ShoppingController($scope, Items) {
        $scope.items = Items.query();
      }
```

But I want to simulate the return of data as async operation via `setTimeout` operation. ( in short - I want to add non-blocking delay)

what have I tried ?

I tried to use `$timeout` variable without any success., also tried to use setTimeout without success (cuz I didnt had `$scope` object inside the method.)

**Question :**

how can I add setTimeout( 3 sec to simulate db operation)  into the factory function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using promises. Modify your code to use something like this:

Factory:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$timeout(function () {
    var returnObj = [
            {title: 'Paint pots', description: 'Pots full of paint', price: 3.95},
            {title: 'Polka dots', description: 'Dots with polka', price: 2.95},
            {title: 'Pebbles', description: 'Just little rocks', price: 6.95}
    ];
    deferred.resolve(returnObj);
}, 3000);

return deferred.promise;
```

And then just call it like this from the controller:

```
$scope.items = Items.query().then(function(res){
    alert(res);
    // successfully resolved
}, function(err) {
    // handle errors
});
```

Comment: do i need jQ for this ?

Comment: No, it uses angular's $q implementation only. You need to inject it as a factory dependency.

Comment: It's just an ng-step towards becoming an ng-master... Or just a promise, if you will. :)

Comment: Hang in there as soon you will encounter ng-enlightenment

Comment: Im writing jsbin for your final confirmation :-)

Comment: Just found something I wrote when I was learning promises: http://jsfiddle.net/whdq4/2/ Note that it uses two levels (see the console to check when the first one ends)... It's pretty useless, but it might help.

Comment: Should be fine now: http://jsbin.com/IWoNase/2/edit You didn't have a return value for the factory, missed the $timeout dependency, returning promise as a function... The rest are cosmetic changes, I think.

Comment: This is more similar to your original code so you can easily track what you missed: http://jsbin.com/amewahoy/1/edit

Comment: I was putting the dependency in an array of string because ive heard that minifiers will change the param value.(`($q, $timeout)`).  and now - after you tried to match my sample with bracket notation - it's much clearer. **thank you very much**.

Comment: p.s. Could I  remove the `$setTimeout` and use plain `setTimeout` with `$apply` ?

Comment: Well, since you need the scope digest, I'd stick with angular's native function (which pretty much does the standard setTimeout and then calls a digest/apply, but still...). I mean, you *can* remove it, of course, if you have reasons.

Comment: off-topic - I think that their api doc is not very intuitive. I mean  - try to search for $watch and youll get nothing. do I need to guess that it comes as a scope property ? lousy documentation.

Comment: The official documentation is **horrible**!!! But you have some nice tutorials here: https://egghead.io/tags/AngularJS